# How to execute a single TypeScript that uses `import type` file in ts-node

Tags: ts-node

I would like to execute a single TypeScript file using `ts-node` as a "module" to take advantage of the `import type` syntax.

When using the `.ts` extension, I get the warning `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.` and then an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`.

When using the `.mts` extension, I get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

What would I need to do to execute a single TypeScript file in `ts-node` and use `import type` without changing the `type` in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I'm using [vite with react](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#trying-vite-online)

In my `tsconfig.json` file, add in this section

```
{
...
"ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
}
```

then simply run `npx ts-node path/to/your/script`